# Junit DB Test results in Incompatible data types error

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I have got a problem considering running a JUnit test for the SQL Updates.

I have got my DAO class and DAO test class similar to:

```
public class generalDao {
//example of getter 
    public Account getAccountById(String id) {
        return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT ac FROM Account ac WHERE ac.accountId = :ID", Account.class).setParameter("ID",id);
    }

//example of update
    public void incrementSubscriberCount(String mnt, Date vf, List<String> accs){
    getEntityManager().createQuery("UPDATE Account ac SET ac.subs = ac.subs+1 WHERE ac.date < :DATE AND ac.mnt = :MNT AND ac.accountId IN (:accs)").setParameter("DATE",vf).setParameter("MNT", mnt).setParameter("accs",accs).executeUpdate();       
    }
}
```

--

```
public class generalDaoTest extends generalDao{
    private static EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void getAccountById(){
    super.getAccountById("1");
    }

    @Test
    public void incrementSubscriberCount(){
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    super.incrementSubscriberCount("5", new Date(), Collections.singletonList("abc"));
    em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```

Also, there are different (longer) and additional methods in the actual classes, these mentioned here are for demonstrative purposes.

My problem there is, that running the test on incrementSubscriberCount() (or rather any method that runs `update` query) which should just validate the SQL will get me following error when test reaches the `executeUpdate()`:

```
WARN  SQL Error: -5562, SQLState: 42562
ERROR  incompatible data types in combination in statement .......
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

Now... I checked all the types, because that is the obvious thing to do with exception sounding like this. 
But all of them are OK.

Also, I tried turning the Update into Select, while keeping the "Where" part the same, just to see if my parameters are wrong.

```
public void incrementSubscriberCount(String mnt, Date vf, List<String> accs){
    getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT ac FROM Account ac 
    WHERE ac.date < :DATE AND ac.mnt = :MNT AND ac.accountId IN (:accs)").setParameter("DATE",vf)
    .setParameter("MNT", mnt).setParameter("accs",accs).getResultList();       
    }
```

And this select works fine. The only thing failing is the `executeUpdate()` method in update.

Another thing that bugs my mind is, that the methods actually work. I mean... when deployed and used, there are no errors. So there has to be some silly error in the test I cannot find.

My test has no assertions, therefore it does not matter if the query finds no row to update. I just need it to pass without crashing.

Project uses Hibernate and the target DB is Oracle.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Of which type is `ac.subs` in your db?

Comment: it is actually a varchar2 (probably for some legacy reasons), but contains numbers only. But since running update on DB using "value = value + 1" works, I came to conclusion that there should be some implicit casting at work.

Comment: On db works indeed but this is hibernate exception. Fiddle around it, try with passing some value without using this internal conversion.

Comment: thank you, will do!

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is that Hibernate is not as lenient with implicit conversions as Oracle itself is.

The exception was caused by trying to subtract number 1 from a string (VARCHAR2) value, therefore the incompatible types exception.

To make it work, I explicitly casted the field to number and then back to string as follows:

```
public void incrementSubscriberCount(String mnt, Date vf, List<String> accs){
getEntityManager().createQuery("UPDATE Account ac SET ac.subs = TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(ac.subs) - 1) 
WHERE ac.date < :DATE AND ac.mnt = :MNT AND ac.accountId IN (:accs)").setParameter("DATE",vf)
.setParameter("MNT", mnt).setParameter("accs",accs).executeUpdate();       
}
```

Since then, the test worked OK.